# Largest Rectangle in terms of area

Tags: geometry

What is the area of the largest rectangle which can be inscribed in a triangle having legs as $3units$ and $4units$. I can do this with differentiation but I want to know that can it be done without it?

I assumed the dimension of the rectangle as $xunits$ on the side $4units$ and $yunits$ on the side $3units$. Then by similarity ${{y} \over 4-x} = {{3} \over 4}$ which implies that $y={{3(4-x)} \over 4}$. Then area =$xy$ that is $3x-{{3x^2} \over 4}$. If area is maximum then ${{3x^2} \over 4}$ must be zero. Now area =$3xunits^2$. If $x>=2$ then area of rectangle will exceed or becomes equal the area of triangle. Now $x=1$ is the only solution and hence area =$3units^2$. But I don't understand why can't x be a real number like $1.5$ or anything like that?

Comment: If area is maximum then $3x^2/4$ must be zero $\leftarrow$ This point is wrong

Comment: "If area is maximum then $\frac{3x^2}{4}$ must be zero" ... what? Why? That would mean $x=0$ and that's not what you want.

Comment: because then it would get subtracted from $'3'$ hence decreasing the value of area

Comment: oh yes i done the whole thing wrong

Comment: It's subtracted from $3x$ and not $3$. There's a world of difference ...

Comment: please tell the correct way

Comment: When you look at expression $3x-3x^2/4$, both $3x$ and $3x^2/4$ increase with $x$, you should find the value of $x$, when $3x^2/4$ starts to increase more rapidly than $3x$

Comment: You could use derivatives or represent $3x-3x^2/4$ as $a-3/4 (b-x)^2$ to find optimum

Comment: yeah but i wan't to know can it be done without deriviate??

Comment: maybe any theorm

Comment: I believe there are not theorem for such a specific case. Represent your expression in the form $a-\frac{3}{4}(b-x)^2$, this expression cannot be greater than $a$, and the maximum is obtained when $x=b$.

Comment: Oh no! There is one property. The rectangle with constant perimeter has maximum area when it is square.

Comment: $3−3(x−2)^2/4$.

Comment: oh thank you i thought there must be a theorm

Comment: You can use along-side contraction of all shapes to make this condition (constant perimeter) true

Comment: yeah thank you very much sir

Comment: but sir here perimeter is not given and if the rectangle is a square then side would be ${ \sqrt{3} \ }/$ is it so? And the answer to this question is 3

Comment: please someone give an answer

Comment: no need to give an answer i understood '

Answer (score 1):

area= ${{3} \over 4}(4-x)x$

$=$ ${{3} \over 4}(4x-x^2)$

$=$ ${{3} \over 4}(4-(x-2^2))$

$=$ $3-{{3} \over 4}(x-2)^2$

Now area is maximum when ${{3} \over 4}(x-2)^2$ $=$ $0$ then $x=2$ ,$y=3/2$